# Launching app post authentication in browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, uiwebview

So I launch a browser(`UIWebView`) in my iOS app for authentication. User types username and password and the request for authentication is posted to a Identity Provider server. It sends the response back in same browser window. Now after successful authentication I want to show first screen of the app. 
This is what I was trying in my Browser `UIWebview` code for this

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   NSURL *url = webView.request.URL;

   if([url.absoluteString containsString:@"DONEWITHLOGIN"]){
      // Store cookies
   }
   // ?? How do I call app delegate from here to launch first screen
   // load custom URL scheme 

}
```

This is what I am doing in my `AppDelegate` now

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
#else
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
#endif
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
#else
        self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
#endif

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// Call Authentication Method - this will launch a webview with URL for authentication 

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication annotation:(id) annotation 
{
   // I return here once the custom URL scheme is loaded.
   // Other code 
        self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
       self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I get the error saying trying to present NavigationController to ViewController whose view is not in hierarchy. Error is coming from line `self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController`.

I am using Cordova for this app.

Comment: The web view will be loaded via the app delegate only . I guess you will have to arrange your view controllers to achieve what you want

Comment: Right now, my app delegate calls this web view which handles authentication, but now I want to return to app delegate after successful authentication...how do I do that?

Comment: you can access app delegate from any where using [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]. Is that what you are looking for ??

Comment: you should use a redirection pattern where you open a specific URL scheme that your application handles correctly.

Comment: @Champoul - now I am using a custom URL scheme ...so after authentication, I call this particular URL scheme, but how do I open the first screen of app in AppDelegate's openURL method

Comment: It seems that rootViewController is a navigation controller, which has a property called viewcontrollers, it is an array, compose the array with your MainViewController.

Comment: @yogsma once you get the delegate callback in your app delegate, you then need to populate correctly the rootViewController of the window associated to your app delegate. If your rootController is a UINavigationController for example, you can instantiate the controllers that are required to be displayed after opening from this URL and setViewControllers: on your UINavigationController. This all depends on how you layout your controllers.

Comment: @Champoul My rootcontroller is not a UINavigationController

Comment: @yogsma at that point we need more information about how your rootController is populated.

Comment: @Champoul I added some more in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions which is currently how I have.

Comment: @yogsma so from what I see, in your openURL implementation of you AppDelegate.m, you should be able to access self.viewController and then perform any modifications there, right ?

Comment: @Champoul I added openURL code ...but now I get the different error. I mentioned the error in post.

Comment: Your question is extremely difficult to follow now with several edits and different code. Try cleaning up making sure that only a minimum example is used. Also make sure to point out where in the code you get the errors you describe.

Comment: I updated the question with edit and also cleaned up.

Comment: @yogsma reseting your window rootController is not really a good practice. .  I thought you wanted to refresh a controller, not recreate the whole hierarchy.  Since you wanna authenticate the user, I agree with Rick's approach to use modal controllers.

Comment: @Champoul Kinda new to iOS, what is a modal controller?

Comment: Please more clarify this question at specific point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are extremely new to iOS so I'll help you out here a little. First off, you should never jump back into the App Delegate to reset views.  You want to load the **MainViewController** inside your app delegate like you are currently doing.  The rest of the code is below!

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController () <WebViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


  if(...userHasAlreadyFilledOutProfileScreen...){
    [self showLoginScreen:NO];
  } else {
    ... show profile screen ...
  }

}

- (void)showLoginScreen:(BOOL)animated
{
  WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
  webViewController.delegate = self;
  [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:animated completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Web View Loaded!");
  }];
}

- (void)showFirstScreenOfApp
{
  ... code to show first screen of app ...
}

- (void)whenUserFinishesProfileScreen
{
  ...

  [self showLoginScreen:YES];

  ...

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**WebViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class WebViewController;
@protocol WebViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)showFirstScreenOfApp;
@end

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController
  @property (nonatomic, assign) id<WebViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView* webView;
@end
```

**WebViewController.m**

```
@implementation WebViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
}

- (void)didLoginCorrectly
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Closed Login WebView");
  }];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  if(...didYouLoginCorrectlySoYouShouldShowFirstScreen... && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showFirstScreenOfApp)]){
    [self.delegate showFirstScreenOfApp];
  }
}

@end
```

**Here's what we're doing**

1. Load the MainViewContoller in AppDelegate
2. Check to see if they filled out profile. If so, show the login screen first without animation so it looks like its the first thing there
3. If they didn't fill out profile page...set that up
4. When they finish the profile page, we set the delegate to the MainViewController and display login page
5. When the user logs in correctly, it dismisses the Login WebViewController.
6. Before the view disappears, it checks to see if you logged in correctly and if so, tells the delegate to show the first screen of the app the logged in user can access

All code between "..." are things you need to fill in as I can't help you with that :)

Hope this helps...ENJOY!

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by going the other way around. Your `MainViewController` is the main view of the application. If the user isn't logged in then it presents a modal view with the login window. Once the login is complete the modal view dismisses itself and stores the credentials in an appropriate way to allow the rest of the app to function.

Comment: How a modal view can dismiss itself?

Comment: I think I understood what you meant...but here is a dilemma with that. Once the user launches app for first time, a profile screen will be launched where user creates a profile with server information, after saving , a login view will be launched (as a modal view controller) and once the user is logged in, modal view controller dismisses, but it brings back to profile creation screen

Comment: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` will make a modal view dismiss itself. For the registration, simply create a second modal view that appears on top of the login. After registration it dismisses itself, the login view is shown and after login it dismisses itself and the app is shown.